# Generated σ-algebra equal to the power set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X = (0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q} $.
Define
$$\mathcal{I} = \{ (a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q}: 0≤a≤b≤1,\ a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$$ and
$$\mathcal{A} = \{ \bigcup_{i=1}^n I_i : n \in \mathbb{N},\ I_1,I_2,...,I_n \in \mathcal{I} \}.$$

I want to show that $\sigma(\mathcal{A}) = \mathcal{P}(X)$.  The only way I can think of to show that this is true is by showing that singletons from $\mathcal{P}(X)$ are in $\sigma (\mathcal{A})$, but proving this seems a bit difficult. Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Given a point $x \in X$ consider $\mathcal{I}_1 = (x,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathcal{I}_n = (0,x-1/n]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ where we define $\mathcal{I}_n = \emptyset$ if $x-1/n<0$. Then,

$$X\setminus \left(\bigcup \mathcal{I}_n\right) = \{x\} \in \sigma(\mathcal{A}).$$

This argument holds for arbitrary $0<x<1$ so $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ contains all singletons except possibly $x=1$.  However, the union of all singletons is countable (by virtue of $X\subset \mathbb{Q}$) and so

$$X\setminus \left(\bigcup_{0<x<1} \{x\}\right) = \{1\} \in \sigma(\mathcal{A}).$$

Then, the result follows since all singletons are contained in $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$.